# Assignment to numpy structured array

Tags: python, numpy

How does one assign to numpy structured arrays?

```
import numpy as np

baz_dtype = np.dtype([("baz1", "str"),
                      ("baz2", "uint16"),
                      ("baz3", np.float32)])
dtype = np.dtype([("foo", "str"),
                  ("bar", "uint16"),
                  ("baz", baz_dtype)])
xx = np.zeros(2, dtype=dtype)
xx["foo"][0] = "A"
```

Here `xx` remains unchanged.  The docs https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.rec.html are a little vague on this.

On a related note, is it possible to make one or more of the subtypes be lists or numpy arrays of the specified dtype?

Any tips welcome.

Comment: Lots of examples of complicated dtypes on: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.dtypes.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're performing the assignment correctly. The part you've screwed up is the *dtypes*. NumPy string dtypes are fixed-size, and if you try to use `"str"` as a dtype, it's treated as **size 0** - the empty string is the only possible value! Your `"A"` gets truncated to 0 characters to fit.

Specify a size - for example, `'S10'` is 10-byte bytestrings, or `'U10'` is 10-code-point unicode strings - or use `object` to store ordinary Python string objects and avoid the length restrictions and treatment of `'\0'` as a null terminator.